# Grounding a soldering iron

Tags: soldering

At school our soldering irons don't have grounded tips. I need one as i'm soldering MOSFETs in to my PCB. So what solutions could I use to ground my soldering iron tip?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No rocket science there - in the simplest case you just take wire, and mechanically connect(no soldering obviously :-) ) it somewhere to your iron, and make sure you 0Ohm resistance between other end of the wire and the tip.

Then connect other side to your grounding - if you don't have one, you should call for electrician to make one - there is no universal way to do it yourself.

But personally, I solder FETs without any grounding, and noone ever failed.

You should only be really worrying about grounding when you work with fragile very high-frequency ones - they indeed are too easy to kill, unlike the majority of FET's and IC's.

Comment: Could i plug the other end in to the ground of my PSU and turn it on?

Comment: @Dean - The earth ground of your PCB should be directly connected to the ground pin in the wall; you shouldn't have to turn it on.  Remember that your PCB is still floating!  It's probably not as bad as the tip of your soldering iron, but you could still develop a potential difference.

Comment: I was somewhat dubious that a dead short to ground would be best, but apparently some [Hakko Irons](http://www.all-spec.com/products/FX951-66.html) have "<2 ohm tip-to-ground resistance" in their specs

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the MOSFET won't care whether your iron is grounded, it will only care if the iron has the same potential as the circuit you're working with (and your body, if you happen to hold the the circuit you're soldering with your hands). Many soldeing irons provide a plug (banana or similar) which you can connect to the ground of your circuit to eliminate ESD. **This only makes sense to do if you already wear a grounding strip**, since your body has much more capacitance which can accumulate electrostatic charges, and most parts are killed by touching them with your hands, not your iron.

If you need to solder a particularly sensitive component with a cheap non-grounded iron, consider disconnecting the iron from mains power before doing so. Such irons tend to have poor insulation from mains, constantly leaking a small current to whatever circuit you touch with it. You may be totally unaware of it (you don't feel a few uA), but it may be enough to damage some sensitive low-voltage parts.

Answer (score 2):

I often like to solder live on a circuit with a grounded low voltage psu, but if my iron is grounded touch the + rail and a short occurs, so I use a 1 Meg resistor in my iron earth leg to prevent this.It will still discharge stray static voltages.It also saves time in keeping to disconnect the psu when soldering on test parts.

Comment: While the ESD part of your answer sounds reasonable, **soldering on a live circuit is a really bad advice to give**. You basically keep powering a circuit which is constantly changing, waiting for Murphy's law to kick in.

Answer (score -1):

If the iron is the 120 volt type that does not use a temperature regulator or transformer you could be at risk. Most 120 volt irons I have seen have the neutral leg tied to the irons tip. This makes it grounded already through the service panel. If the outlet is wired wrong, the tip could be at the "hot" leg potential. If you try to ground the tip then the circuit breaker will trip on overload, or worse you could be injured. Also if reversed and ungrounded, you could be putting 120 volts AC into your circuit. I personally never use a ground on the iron and have never blown a chip. Most semiconductors today have adequate esd protection.

Comment: "_Most 120 volt irons I have seen have the neutral leg tied to the irons tip._" I have never seen such a dangerous practice and doubt that it could ever meet _any_ legal safety standards.

Comment: Specifically in countries without keyed plugs...

Comment: @transistor, is there a better way to do so with a two-pronged iron?

Comment: @rsaxvc, see the accepted answer.

Comment: @transistor, I'm not asking about grounding the iron tip externally. I'm asking about how it should be connected in the iron. Should it be disconnected instead of connected to neutral?

Comment: It should be disconnected.

Answer (score -1):

Do not ground your soldering iron directly!! do so through a large value resistor. Touching a soldering tip to a device which has a static charge build should discharge that voltage through a large value resistor and not to a direct short to ground. I always ground my soldering iron tips through a few hundred thousand K or even through a Meg. It prevents damage to debices by limiting the discharge current to say nothing for how it prevents sparks when I stupidly touch the tip to a live circuit.
In short. GROUND YOUR SOLDERING IRON THROUGH A MEG OHM RESISTOR.

Comment: This is conflict with actual industry practice.  Get an ohm meter and a quality solder station, and you will find there is actually a very low resistance, possibly a direct connection.  You are likely confusing things with the case of an anti-static strap, where a resistor is provided for *operator safety* as the strap cannot be readily / involuntarily removed should a path from a live circuit through the operator's body and the strap to ground occur.

Comment: A mains powered iron should have the shaft (and hence the tip) earthed properly to mains earth. This will ensure that the fuse or RCD/GFCI trips in the event of an internal fault. Also consider the risk to the operator when holding solder and touching it with a live tip.

Comment: @Transistor I thought GFCI didn't require grounding since it detects a voltage differences between the hot and neutral.

Comment: @user148298: correct, but I'd rather the GFCI detect a current going to ground through the iron's earth connection rather than through me. GFCIs can fail to operate.